# How to Print PDF through javascript without using iframes

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf

I want to print a PDF when a button is clicked through javascript. i don't want to use iframes.
Can any one help me?

Comment: Nope.  You need to use an `<iframe>`.

Comment: Until PDF viewers are built into more browsers (only Chrome has one atm, I believe, and one on the way for FF), an iframe is the only option, as a plugin must get invoked.

Comment: I tried to print with iframes but its not working for firefox. Works perfectly for chrome. Tried different code given by many forms. but nothing worked. So I thought of getting rid of iframe.

Answer (score 0):

If your user doesn't have a PDF printer driver, you'd have to use something like this:

http://badassjs.com/post/708922912/pdf-js-create-pdfs-in-javascript

or perhaps a PDF webservice like one of these:

http://blog.nitropdf.com/index.php/2008/01/23/free-online-web-services-to-create-view-share-and-edit-pdf-files/

Comment: He (seems to) wants to print an existing PDF

Comment: I have a PDF exists in my system. I just want to print that PDF.